# Windows 7 Home Premium serial

Tags: windows-7, product-key, windows-activation

I have **windows 7 Home Premium**  , now I want to format my laptop and then re-install the same window version , so before I do that I got an screenshot of `computer > properties`   , which is shown below

[image]

Does the field of `Product ID` has  enough details in order to activate again for **Windows 7 Home Premium** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, probably not.

When you reinstall windows on a Non-OEM machine you will be asked for a key. That key is written on the CoA sticker (the one you said is too blurry to read).

They key is **not the one shown on your screenshot**.

The product ID in your screenshot is derived from that key, and you might get lucky and convince a human operator to give you the right key based on that. *Might*.

What you want is to discover restore the correct key based on that product key. [This](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) is the tool I usually use for that. And [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/tp/topkeyfinder.htm) is a page with links to 14 more similar products.

Comment: OK thanks .  About the CoA sticker  , I think that I discover the key written on him but I'm not sure if I read it ok, is there any way to ensure that it's that right key before I reinstall the windows  ?  .

Comment: No. Worst case you can try to install windows in a VM, or on another computer, or one the same computer after swapping in another HDD. (Thus testing it during an actual install without wiping the old one). That does not seem to be an efficient way of testing it though. -- Or getting it from the documentation on your computer. I might be the only person who documented that CoA number though (I did so after I had a similar problem with a Dell laptop where the CoA is on the bottom of the laptop and becomes unreadable after a year).

Answer (score 2):

I recently had an occasion to reinstall my Win 7 computer from the initial DVD.  I did not have any problems in the activation process and I used the original product key (from the manufacturer sticker on my machine).  So therefore, I say YES that information is sufficient.

Comment: In which case of the installation I required to enter this product key  ?

Comment: YES, you'll be asked by the Windows installation process for the product ID/key at some point early.

Comment: If you have an OEM setup then you might never get asked that since the installation will activate itself based on a key in your BIOS. If it does ask, please enter the key based on the blurry CoA sticker, not the product ID from your screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way would be to locate the Windows Product Key sticker.  Normally this is located on the bottom of a laptop, or on the top or back of a desktop.  If you are unable to find the sticker on your laptop, it may be under the battery.

As Tanner has posted, programs such as [the Magical Jelly Bean](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) are also useful in this situation as it will grab more than just the Windows product key (programs such as Adobe products, Microsoft Office, etc.).

Comment: I know  ... but unfortunately this sticker becames very blurred so I can't read the text on him , therefor I asked about the **Product ID**.

Comment: @URL87 Understood.  Ignore my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

No, with Product ID you can't reinstall Windows 7. If you lost the serial number you must buy a new copy, because Windows 7 do not store any serial number like older Windows versions you can't recover it with software.

Comment: You're right about the Product ID, but not about retrieval of the Product Key (which *can* be recovered).

Comment: It happened to me with Windows 8 and after using the KeyFinder software, I was surprised that the serial did not work... I had to buy a new license.

Comment: Windows 8 is different. On new Win8 PCs the key is embedded in the BIOS and there is no COA sticker any more.

Comment: You're right, but what I mean is that the KeyFinder tool does not always work in both Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: I've not used it with Win8 yet, but it's never failed me in Win7 so far. Anyway, the question was about Win7 and I guess it's been answered satisfactorily.